# yui2 and yui3 events

Tags: javascript, dom-events, yui, yui3

Can the yui3 construct of `Y.on()` be used to setup listeners for events on yui2 widgets, or do they simply use separate event systems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They use separate event systems.  However, you can use Y.on() to set up DOM listeners that trigger methods on YUI 2 Widgets.

```
Y.on('focus', Y.bind(myCalendar.show, myCalendar), '#birthdate');
```

or more generically

```
Y.on('click', function () {
    /* do other stuff... */

    myDataSource.sendRequest('filter=active', {
        success: myDataTable.onDataReturnInitializeTable,
        scope: myDataTable
    });

    /* ...and more stuff */
}, '#date-filter');
```

Y.on() can't be used to subscribe to widget custom events in YUI 2, though.

```
Y.on('activeTabChange', thisWontWork, myTabView); // does nothing
```

Comment: If someone can add working example then that will be better. What is "myDataSource" here!

Comment: In this example, it represents the YUI 2 YAHOO.util.DataSource instance that needs to respond to a click on the #date-filter element.